# How to get another value from different table in php

Tags: php

```
$sql = "SELECT users.user_name, users.password, profil.name
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN
    profil ON users.id = profil.id
    WHERE user_name='admin' AND password='123'
    ORDER BY profil.name;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

echo $_SESSION['name']
```

table:user
| user_name| pass | id  |
| -------- | -----|-----|
| admin    | 123  |  1  |
| admini   | 123  |  2  |

table : profil
| id | name    |
| ---| --------|
| 1  | ajramos |
| 2  | carlo   |
how can i print the name when i log in a account

i wanted to display the name when i log in a acc for example admin 123 ajramos should print

Comment: the thing is my query works on sql but idont know how to print it

Answer (score 0):

you have to execute the query and save into a session

```php
$sql = "SELECT users.user_name as user_name, users.password, profil.name as name 
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN
    profil ON users.id = profil.id
    WHERE user_name='admin' AND password='123'
    ORDER BY profil.name LIMIT 1;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
   
$_SESSION['login_data'] = $data;
echo $_SESSION['login_data']['name'];
```